# Convert local time to UTC in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm supporting a legacy system written in Delphi 7. The system writes records to the data base with *GMT+n local time* as one of its parameters. I need to use the records but the time zone is a problem.
I want to convert them to UTC time.
Updating Delphi's version is not an option (that's why I can't use the new functions of newer Delphi versions), and the conversion cannot occur in the DB.

Assuming the system is not using daylight saving time, how do I convert the records after fetching them?